# Debugging Xamarin app using Safari Web Inspector with iOS16.4 not working

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, safari

On a Mac with the iOS Simulator running, if I go to Safari -> Develop, it shows "no inspectable applications".  You used to be able to inspect the web page in the simulator but looks like Apple eliminated that with iOS 16.4.  You seem to need to mark the WKWebView as inspectable (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/4111163-inspectable/) by setting that property to true since it defaults to false.  I've found examples of how to do that in Swift or Objective-C but nothing for Xamarin.  Any idea how to do this in Xamarin?

https://webkit.org/blog/13936/enabling-the-inspection-of-web-content-in-apps/

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:[How do I enable inspection?](https://webkit.org/blog/13936/enabling-the-inspection-of-web-content-in-apps/), if you want to enable the Web Inspector, you need to set the `Inspectable` property to **true** for the **WKWebView**:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(WebView), typeof(MyWebViewRenderer))]
namespace .....
{
      public class MyWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<WebView, WKWebView>
      {

            WKWebView wKWebView;
            public MyWebViewRenderer()
            {
            }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
                  if (Control != null) return;

                  var config = new WKWebViewConfiguration();
                  wKWebView = new WKWebView(Frame, config);


                  if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(16, 0)) {
                   wKWebView.Inspectable = true;
            }
            

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Write below renderer in iOS platform of Xamarin Forms
2. Don't forgot to turnoff/switch from private browser in safari, because if safari enabled with private browsers, inspect is not working in iOS 16.7

```
    using Foundation;
    using App.iOS;
    using Xamarin.Forms;
    using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
    
    [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(WebView), typeof(CustomWebViewRenderer))]
    namespace App.iOS
    {
        public class CustomWebViewRenderer : WkWebViewRenderer
        {
            protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                base.OnElementChanged(e);
    
                if (NativeView != null && e.NewElement != null)
                {
                    var webView = NativeView;
    
                    if (webView == null)
                        return;
    
                    webView.SetValueForKey(NSObject.FromObject(true), new NSString("inspectable"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```